# Is there an automated way of creating multiple individual feature classes from one feature class in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, sql

I have a feature class with more than 6000 unique values. Rather than having this as one feature class, I would like to create 6000 individual feature classes. Meaning, for each row in the attribute table, I would like to make its own feature class.

Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS Pro or Python? How can I automate this rather than manually doing the Export Feature tool?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Split by attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm):

> Splits an input dataset by unique attributes.